# Accuracy Excel.Chart

Tags: c#, excel

How can I specify the accuracy of the data in the diagram? The second first character after the decimal point is of interest.

```
Excel.Range chartRange; 
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartPage.ApplyDataLabels(XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, false, true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false);
String destPath = "";
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("D2", "E6");
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xl3DPieExploded;

//export chart as picture file
destPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
chartPage.ApplyDataLabels(XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, false, true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false);
chartPage.DisplayBlanksAs = Excel.XlDisplayBlanksAs.xlZero;
chartPage.Export(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dig1.bmp", "BMP", misValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can set the format of the value presented by the DataLables. For example:

```
chartPage.SeriesCollection(1).NumberFormat = "##.###";
```

More about DataLabels [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/datalabels-object-excel)

Comment: "System.__ComObject" not content "NumberFormat" [transtale]